# Are there any disadvantages to using a mining pool with I2P?

Tags: mining-pools, i2p

Recently, MoneroWorld added a [mining port for I2P](https://moneroworld.com/#i2p). Are there any disadvantages to mining with I2P instead of connecting to the pool directly? Eg: will it be sgnificantly harder to submit shares? Is the connection less reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is significant (and variable) lag in the i2p network - try visiting any i2p website. As mentioned on MoneroWorld.com, this could cause an increase in stale shares (you submit a solution for a block that already has been solved).

i2p lag will only decrease if more and more people run i2p nodes. (and by i2p nodes I mean running the i2p server).

Comment: If you had to estimate, what percentage of shares would be lost this way?

Comment: Can't estimate...

Answer (score 1):

Might be used to give an edge to unauthorized remotely controlled botnets, a disadvantage.
Prevents retribution for those ensuring health of the Monero mining network with their resources, an advantage.